# MongoDB - how to scale with One huge collection and many small ones?

Tags: spring, mongodb

We are using mongoDB for our web application.
The application has a requirement to be super fast and responsive.
The DB contains 10-20 small collections and 1 huge collection that constantly growing rapidly.

The huge collection is persisting history information that can be fetched by api users we expose on the server like so:

```
  GET: http://app.com/history/5318a72ea0fc598286e7bbaf
```

while the '5318a72ea0fc598286e7bbafis' the _id of that document.

We are using a replication set with 1 primary, and 2 secondaries (one is hidden).

Our questions are:

1) Is the growth of the huge collection can hit our web app performance?

2) If so - How can we scale up ? is it possible to shard a single collection? if so is that a good idea?

3) To increase our webapp performance, Should we separate the huge collection to a different db? (if so - shouldn't mongoDB be able to handle big data properly?)

Thanks!

Comment: ~250K new documents added each day, maybe more. its hard to tell now but we would like to be ready for all scenarios

Comment: Can you define more precisely "super fast and responsive"?

Comment: Well our customers will want to invoke an api to fetch the history documents for example, it shouldn't take too long (think of api of webservices response time)

Comment: Will you only be fetching by id from the large collection, or will you be running queries against the documents?

Comment: Only fetching by id from the huge collection, the other collections might be queried with more complex queries

Answer (score 1):

A bit hard to answer this question without sounding opinionated, but here's a go;

1) Yes, a huge collection may lower performance, although you can go pretty far doing unique key lookups as you're doing without seeing much degradation. In the long run though, if you keep on adding documents at that pace and have a decent amount of lookups sharding will probably be required to keep performance up.

2) Yes, you can easily shard a single collection. As your id is unique, sharding with a [hashed shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/shard-collection-with-a-hashed-shard-key/) on that id should be a good option and provide good performance.

3) I see no reason to separate the collections into separate DBs unless your performance requirements are extreme.